# Does a setinterval in a componentDidMount Function Create a New Thread Each Run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple web application where time is displayed and updated every millisecond. My code is below:

```
class Time extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: "",
      time: ""
    }
    this.updateTime = this.updateTime.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.updateTime, 1);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  updateTime() {
    let dateObject = new Date();
    let date = dateObject.toDateString();
    let hour = dateObject.getHours().toString();
    let minute = dateObject.getMinutes().toString();
    let second = dateObject.getSeconds().toString();
    let millisecond = dateObject.getMilliseconds().toString();
    let time = hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second + " : " + millisecond;
    this.setState({
      date: date,
      time: time
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TitleBar/>
        <div className="time-div">
          <p className="date-txt" value={this.state.date}> {this.state.date} </p>
          <p className="time-txt" value={this.state.time}> {this.state.time} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Time;
```

Considering that the componentDidMount function runs when the Time component is mounted, my question is the following:

Does the setInterval function inside this componentDidMount function remember itself every interval run? Or, does it componentDidMount function run again and the setInterval function inside it creates a new thread?

Basically, what I'm asking is, does the program run like:

1. component is mount? CHECK --> setInterval every millisecond to run updateTime function --> component is mount? CHECK --> "returning to same" setInterval function to continue the next interval of updateTime function --> ... etc.
   OR
2. component is mount? CHECK --> setInterval every millisecond to run updateTime function --> component is mount? CHECK --> "does not remember" the initial setInterval function and starts a new interval *whilst* continuing the initial setInterval function --> ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` runs on initial render only and not on state updates.
So when you have used.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.updateTime, 1);
  }
```

The `setInterval` will start initially and this process will keep running in the background.

Until you `Unmount` your component in which case the `Clean up` will happen for the `setInterval`.

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
```

Comment: Sure Mate :) Happy coding... Would advice you to  look into useEffect() Hook... Hooks are awsome...